# About the word "race" when talking about bike headset

Tags: terminology

I can't find any definition of "race" in its use for example on this page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Headset_(bicycle_part)

on Cambridge or Oxford dictionaries...

Someone can tell me where this word comes from ?

Comment: The [very first instance of race](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_(bearing)) on the page links to an explanation of what it is. Did that not answer your question?

Comment: @Laurel, the OP knows what a bearing race is, but wants to know where it comes from, I think.  A reasonable question, since Etymonline doesn't show the definition at first blush.

Answer (score 1):

It's the third sense listed on [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/race):

> **3** : a track or channel in which something rolls or slides
>
> *specifically* : a groove for the balls in a ball bearing or rollers in a roller bearing

The analogy with a mill race seems plausible, but I haven't made any effort to check it (and it's an independent meaning now, anyway).

Answer (score 0):

"Bearing race" applies to many situations beyond bicycles.  My impression has been that it's used mainly for ball bearings, to refer to the slot where the bearings run.  I suspect that this is by analogy to a mill race ([millrace](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/millrace)) and similar concepts:

> : a canal in which water flows to and from a mill wheel
> also : the current that drives the wheel

Answer (score 0):

"A track or channel in which something rolls or slides" - [merriam-webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/race)

Answer (score 0):

Lexico (powered by Oxford) has [a definition of Race](https://www.lexico.com/definition/race) that is as follows

4. A smooth ring-shaped groove or guide in which a ball bearing or roller bearing runs.

Which describes its use in a bike headset.